# When are levels generated?

Tags: diablo-iii

Are levels generated at the game's start or on demand as the room is entered? Once a room is generated, will it or its contents (features/drops/enemies) ever reset or change if I wait in another area for long enough?

Comment: Since levels are persistent once generated, does it matter if they are created on entry or game start? What is the functional difference?

Comment: The entire Act is generated the amount of data that would be required to hold the important information would be trivial.  What the enemies drop are generated at death.

Answer (score 2):

You have to Leave Game in the pause menu in order to get new areas generated once you've visited them.

I'm not sure whether the levels are generated when you reach them or when you start the Act/game/area, but it doesn't really matter - either way the only way to get new levels generated is to leave that game.